# How to show column headers in a GtkTreeView inside a gtk.ScrolledWindow?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview, scrolledwindow

I have a problem with `Gtk.Treeview` indide a `Gtk.ScrolledWindow`. I have a large amount of data, which doesnt fit inside my normal window geometrics, so i put my Treeview inside a `ScrolledWindow`, which seems to be the normal way. The problem with this solution is, that my Column Headers disapear, when I scroll. This behaviour seems somewhat ok to me, since the `ScrolledWindow` should care about the widgets inside of it.

So, how do I get my Treeview to be scrollable **AND** show the column headers always in the first row?

I modified the *basictreeview.py* example to represent my problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# example basictreeview.py

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class BasicTreeViewExample:

    # close the window and quit
    def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()
        return False

    def __init__(self):
        # Create a new window
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.set_title("Basic TreeView Example")
        self.window.set_size_request(200, 200)
        self.window.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)

        # create a TreeStore with one string column to use as the model
        self.liststore = gtk.ListStore(str)

        # we'll add some data now - 4 rows with 3 child rows each
        for i in range(10):
            self.liststore.append([str(i)])

        # create the TreeView using treestore
        self.treeview = gtk.TreeView(self.liststore)

        # create the TreeViewColumn to display the data
        self.tvcolumn = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Column-Name", gtk.CellRendererText(), text=0)

        # add tvcolumn to treeview
        self.treeview.append_column(self.tvcolumn)

        # make it searchable
        self.treeview.set_search_column(0)

        # Allow sorting on the column
        self.tvcolumn.set_sort_column_id(0)

        # Allow drag and drop reordering of rows
        self.treeview.set_reorderable(True)

        # Add Treeview to a ScrolledWindow
        self.scrolledwindow = gtk.ScrolledWindow(hadjustment=None, vadjustment=None)
        self.scrolledwindow.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
        self.scrolledwindow.add_with_viewport(self.treeview)

        self.window.add(self.scrolledwindow)

        self.window.show_all()

def main():
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tvexample = BasicTreeViewExample()
    main()
```

Comment: Can you find an application that does this? If so, your best bet is to look in the source code. As far as I know, there's no easy way to do this with GtkTreeView.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change `self.scrolledwindow.add_with_viewport` to `self.scrolledwindow.add` and it will work. From [the documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkscrolledwindow.html#method-gtkscrolledwindow--add-with-viewport):

> The add_with_viewport() method is used to add a widget (specified by child) without native scrolling capabilities to the scrolled window. This is a convenience function that is equivalent to adding child to a gtk.Viewport, then adding the viewport to the scrolled window. If a child has native scrolling (e.g. gtk.TextView, gtk.TreeView, gtk.Layout), use gtk.Container.add() instead of this method.

`gtk.TreeView`'s "native scrolling" keeps the column headers at the top, but if you put the entire treeview widget in a `gtk.Viewport` first, then the entire widget will scroll.